# Sharedpreferences Error (2 activities)

Tags: android

I have 2 Activities. In "A" activity I have a button and when user clicks this button, "B" Activity long data will change.

If the user doesn't click this button, in "B" Activity change standard long data...

Here is my code in "A" Activity's button;

```
 SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("sure", MODE_PRIVATE);
              SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
              editor.putString("veri", "31000");
              editor.commit();
```

Here is my code in "B" Activity's for get;

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("sure", MODE_PRIVATE); 
long kalansure = prefs.getLong("veri", 61000);
```

But it is not working...

Comment: You are putting the String and getting a Long. That wont work

Comment: The method putLong(String, long) in the type SharedPreferences.Editor is not applicable for the arguments (String, String)

Comment: Well passing string and string wont work, what do u not underdstand? Simply pass string,long :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `putString` in `A` and then `getLong` in `B`. You should either use `String` in both places or `long` in both places, depending on what you need.

Comment: @Eren It's because `"31000"` is a string. You need to write `editor.putLong("veri", 31000L);`

Comment: You need to ask another question on that, including all the code and the stack trace. If this answer helped, don't forget you can mark it as correct by clicking the tick next to it.